# is it possible if there are multi autocompletes then if user is one 2nd autocomplete and list is opened user hovered on some value and

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, autocomplete, tabs, textinput

I try some ref and focus , blur , input change methods but not get the right flow, and also i have tried some other ways applied my logic in different scenarios but not succeed.
I think this flow needs some jQuery related things if I am not wrong people here will correct me